# Backing up large amounts of data

Tags: backup

So I have a large RAID external drive that backs up to a second RAID external drive of the same size. By large amounts I'm talking like 10 TB. As you can imagine, creating such a large backup from scratch would take immense amounts of time, so incremental backups are a necessity.

I have been using Comodo backup. One problem I'm having is there is only enough space on the backup drive for a single backup.

I'm doing incremental backups. But if an incremental backup were to have an error, this would spoil the entire backup correct? I couldn't revert to an earlier backup since there is only space for 1 backup.

I have looked into split backups. If there is a backup error does this mean only the piece where the error occurred would have to be backed up from scratch?

Basically if there is an error I don't want the entire backup to be spoiled.

How to best handle this concern (e.g. tools to use, best practices, etc)? Thanks!

Edit:
The tool must properly backup hardlinks

Comment: *Must* you backup regularly (e.g nightly)? Or, would you be willing to mirror? One huge copy and then every time a single file gets changed that change is immediately reflected on the backup drive? I am doing that with 6TB and **highly** recommend https://bvckup2.com/

Comment: Mirror sounds like a good idea. Then if there is an error backing up a changed file, only the newly backed up file is affected? I guess then my only problem would be as I change a file on one a file gets changed on the other which could slow real time performance (since if you were to create a large file, E.G. downloading a video, that large video gets downloaded to the backup as well). So maybe schedule the mirroring to take place at night or something? Would that be possible?

Comment: Nope: if it is scheduled, then it is, by nature, a backup. Mirroring happens at once. However, I tend to download a lot of (legal) videos and have not noticed any slowing. YMMV; so suck it & see

Comment: bvckup2.com looks like a cool tool but I need a tool that will properly backup hardlinks and it looks like this tool does not.

Comment: Well, the author was looking at adding support 2.5 years ago http://bvckup2.com/news/02-11-2012  Perhaps you can email him & confirm? After all, you have no othehr suggestion so far

Comment: Currently looking at another tool but I'm still evaluating it. It does mirroring but not in real time, but that may be acceptable to me because I can't really find many tools that properly back up hardlinks.

Comment: Could you name the tool, in case it helps others?

Comment: ln.exe, looks like its fast and perfectly mirrors the primary hardlinks, junctions, symlinks and all but doesn't have a UI and doesn't do it real time, but may be good enough for me once I get everything set up...

Comment: Does it have a URL, so that others can look at it? And, if it doesn't do it real-time, is it really mirroring?

Comment: Simple google search on "ln.exe" first result. I don't think mirroring has to be real time, it just mirrors what's on the disk when the command is run. Hence the --mirror option.

Comment: Result vary according to user - based on country, previous search history, etc. Couldn't you just post the link? Not just for me, but for anyone who reads this in future?  As to "real-time", sue a few sceonds might not make a great difference. So long as it's not "let's do it overnight". Deferring like that seems to me to be backup, not really mirroring. But let's not quibble over terminology. Let's find you a good application.

Comment: Well, I see that @Wes has only 7 points, so I fear that he has abandoned the site, so we may never get an accepted answer to this :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html

I use the Smart Mirror option, running it every 30 minutes with Windows Task Scheduler and it works great, perfectly mirroring the primary.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. We want answers that explain how the recommended product matches the requirements and fits the purpose of the question. Could you expand it to demonstrate how this product fits? See [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356) for tips on writing an answer.

Comment: The website talks about a tool that can be used for backups, which is what the topic is about. I don't know what else to say really...

Comment: I also wrote the question so you can be sure my answer answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26850/sync-two-folder-in-one-windows-machine-in-realtime/26855#26855) ...

You don't mention that it must be free. I would highly recommend paying US $19.99 for a personal version of [Bvckup 2](https://www.bvckup2.com/). I did, and I have never regretted it.

I did a lot of research before choosing it, and what convinced me was partly that it supports VSS, so that it can synch files which are in use, and, especially, the speed, it wins every test because it uses [delta copying](https://www.bvckup2.com/#delta-copying):

> Reduce the amount of data being moved around by copying modified parts
>   of files only. This speeds things up, in many cases dramatically.

[image].

There is a 5 start review of it at [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2369334/review-bvckup-2-is-lean-mean-and-not-a-competitor-to-time-machine.html).

If you don't want to spend, or just want to try it out, the last beta, which is quite recent, is available [here](https://www.bvckup2.com/#).

If you still don't like Bvckup2, then I can highly recommend [FreeFileSynch](http://www.freefilesync.org/), which I previously used. See my long answers to [this SR question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/which-backup-sync-software-for-me/14708#14708), and [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/free-automatic-backup-tool-for-windows/17326#17326) and [this one too](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/syncronization-software-with-smart-update/15071#15071).

To save you the trouble of clicking those links, here is the feature list:

> ```
> Key Features
>
> Detect moved and renamed files and folders
> Copy locked files (Volume Shadow Copy Service)
> Detect conflicts and propagate deletions
> Binary file comparison
> Configure handling of Symbolic Links
> Automate sync as a batch job
> Process multiple folder pairs
> Comprehensive and detailed error reporting
> Copy NTFS extended attributes (compressed, encrypted, sparse)
> Copy NTFS security permissions
> Support long file paths with more than 260 characters
> Fail-safe file copy
> Cross-platform: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X
> Expand environment variables like %USERPROFILE%
> Access variable drive letters by volume name (USB sticks)
> Native 64-bit support
> Keep versions of deleted/updated files
> Prevent disc space bottlenecks via optimal sync sequence
> Full Unicode support
> Highly optimized runtime performance
> Include/exclude files via filter
> FreeFileSync portable and local installation available
> Handle daylight saving time changes on FAT/FAT32
> Use macros %time%, %date%, et al. for recurring backups
> Case-sensitive synchronization
> Built-in locking: serialize multiple jobs running against the same network share 
>
> Supported Operating Systems
>
> Microsoft Windows Microsoft Windows FreeFileSync runs natively on all 32 and 64-bit Windows versions:
>
> Windows 10
> Windows 8.1
> Windows 8
> Windows 7
> Windows Vista
> Windows XP
> Windows 2000
> ```